# How can i use XSL sheet to filter C# Application

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transformation

I apologize if I am not explaining this right.

I need to create a c# application that when a value is selected from a combobox, it will supposed to filter out and transform my XSLT sheet. I have 3 different criteria in the combobox that makes this challenging. what i'm stuck on right now is designing the XLST, since the criteria is different.

Here is my XSLT sheet so far, which displays all my information.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >    

    <xsl:variable name="features" select="programming/features/feature" />

    <xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Programming</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th >Programming</th>
        <th >Intended Use</th>
       <xsl:for-each select="$features">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        <th style="text-align:left">Standards</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="programming/languages/language">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:variable name="intendedUseID" select="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse[@id=$intendedUseID]" >
           <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br  />
        </xsl:for-each></td>


         <xsl:variable name="my-features" select="features/feature" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$features">
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="@id = $my-features/@id">Yes</xsl:if>
            </td>
            </xsl:for-each>


        <td>   <xsl:variable name="standardID" select="standards/standard/@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/programming/standards/standard[@id=$standardID]" >
           <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br />
        </xsl:for-each></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="language">
    <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="my-features" select="features/feature" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$features">
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="@id = $my-features/@id">Yes</xsl:if>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<programming>
  <languages>
    <language id="1">
      <name>C</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="4" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="4" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="2">
      <name>C++</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="3">
      <name>C#</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="5" />
        <intendedUse id="6" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
        <feature id="6" />
        <feature id="7" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="4">
      <name>Java</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="6" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="5" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="4" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="5">
      <name>JavaScript</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="6">
      <name>PHP</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="5" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="7">
      <name>Python</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
        <intendedUse id="10" />
        <intendedUse id="11" />
        <intendedUse id="12" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="5" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="8">
      <name>Basic</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="13" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="4" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="9">
      <name>ADA</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
        <intendedUse id="14" />
        <intendedUse id="15" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
        <standard id="6" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="10">
      <name>ActionScript 3.0</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="7" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
      </standards>
    </language>
  </languages>

  <purpose>
    <intendedUse id="1"> Application</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="2"> System </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="3"> General Purpose </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="4"> Low-Level Operations </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="5"> RAD </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="6"> Business </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="7"> Client-Side </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="8"> Server-Side </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="9"> Web </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="10"> Scripting </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="11"> AI </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="12"> Scientific Computing </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="13">Education</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="14">Embedded</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="15">RealTime</intendedUse>
  </purpose>
  <features>
    <feature id="1">Imperative </feature>
    <feature id="2">Object-Oriented</feature>
    <feature id="3">Functional</feature>
    <feature id="4">Procedural</feature>
    <feature id="5">Generic</feature>
    <feature id="6">Reflective</feature>
    <feature id="7">Event-Driven</feature>
  </features>
  <standards>
    <standard id="1">ANSI</standard>
    <standard id="2">ISO</standard>
    <standard id="3">ECMA</standard>
    <standard id="4">DE FACTO</standard>
    <standard id="5">NO</standard>
    <standard id="6">GOST</standard>
  </standards>
</programming>
```

Below is a screenshot of the combobox. [image]

Basically, if i select an intended use, standard, it should display all the languages associated with that criteria.

Here is the code for the output

```
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Programming</th>
        <th>Intended Use</th>
        <th>Imperative </th>
        <th>Object-Oriented</th>
        <th>Functional</th>
        <th>Procedural</th>
        <th>Generic</th>
        <th>Reflective</th>
        <th>Event-Driven</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Standards</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td> Application<br> System <br> General Purpose <br> Low-Level Operations <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ANSI<br>ISO<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C++</td>
        <td> Application<br> System <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ISO<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C#</td>
        <td> Application<br> General Purpose <br> RAD <br> Business <br> Client-Side <br> Server-Side <br> Web <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>ISO<br>ECMA<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Java</td>
        <td> Application<br> General Purpose <br> Business <br> Client-Side <br> Server-Side <br> Web <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>DE FACTO<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>JavaScript</td>
        <td> Client-Side <br> Server-Side <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ECMA<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PHP</td>
        <td> Server-Side <br> Web <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>NO<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Python</td>
        <td> Application<br> General Purpose <br> Web <br> Scripting <br> AI <br> Scientific Computing <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>NO<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Basic</td>
        <td> Application<br>Education<br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ANSI<br>ISO<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ADA</td>
        <td> Application<br> System <br>Embedded<br>RealTime<br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>ANSI<br>ISO<br>GOST<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ActionScript 3.0</td>
        <td> Application<br> Client-Side <br> Web <br></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>ECMA<br></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using XSLT, then I am guessing you have some XML you are transforming. Would it be possible to show the XML in this case? It sounds like you need to use some parameters though (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: adding my XML. im wondering. is there a way how I can apply the transformation during certain conditions?

Comment: And would it be possible for you to post the expected output HTML code, and not just the screenshot of it?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass parameters from your code to the XSL transformation? For that, use XsltArgumentList. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dfktf882%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sounds like parameters are the way to go. I'm new at this. I'll update my answer if I figure it out.